# Чем отличается overflow: hidden от visibility: hidden?

Tags: html, css

Разбирал анимацию появления текста и заметил строчку: `overflow: hidden` - сразу попробовал заменить эту строчку на  `visibility: hidden` чтобы проверить будет ли результат таким же, но результат был уже другим, встал вопрос: чем же они отличаются.

Вот полный код программы:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.text_anim {
  width: 26ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 36px;
  animation: text_displaying 5s steps(26) infinite;
  -moz-animation: text_displaying 5s steps(26) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: text_displaying 5s steps(26) infinite;
  -o-animation: text_displaying 5s steps(26) infinite;
}

@keyframes text_displaying {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes text_displaying {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes text_displaying {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes text_displaying {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrap">
    <span class="text_anim">Text-displaying animation.</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Я пришёл домой и сразу заменил стеклянное окно на стеклянный стакан, но результат был совершенно другим. Чем они отличаются?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это совершенно разные свойства. [Overflow](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow) управляет переполнением элемента (т.е. тем, как будут отображаться дочерние элементы, если они выходит за пределы родителя), а [visibility](http://htmlbook.ru/css/visibility) - видимостью самого элемента.